# Getting below error with building bundle(s) with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, javacv, android-ffmpeg

Try to build bundles with javacv library getting error in x86_64 and arm-v8a ABI

```
com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$
  FileUsesReservedNameException:File 'root/lib/x86_64/include/opencv2/bioinspired.hpp' 
  uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.
```

I'm using javacv and ffmpeg library for my project and as it's compulsory to add 64-bit ABI on play store and APK size also increased so I want to build bundle(s) for that but getting this error thanks

Comment: add more explain for your question.

Comment: Please add above comment to your original question.